# XCode 7.0.1 fails to launch

Tags: xcode

I recently found myself in a position where I needed to update my Xcode from 6.4 to 7. However, Xcode 7 "quits unexpectedly" while trying to launch with this error listed in the error message. Anyone know whats going on?

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: DVTPlugInExtensionFaultingLock

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 7A1001
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Extension Xcode.InterfaceBuilderKit.CocoaIntegrator.Integrator.NSCollectionViewGridLayout class 'NSCollectionViewGridLayout' not found for required key 'integratedClass'
UserInfo: {
    DVTExtensionClassNameErrorKey = NSCollectionViewGridLayout;
    DVTExtensionIdentifierErrorKey = "Xcode.InterfaceBuilderKit.CocoaIntegrator.Integrator.NSCollectionViewGridLayout";
    DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration.ideplugin";
    DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey = "com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration";
}
```

Comment: I solved some startup problem in Xcode by deleting some stuff from the xcode cache directory in the library folder. I forgot what problem I had. But maybe it is a useful search direction :-)

Comment: Have you tried removing Xcode and reinstalling?

Comment: hm do you have some specific pointers for deleting things in the cache? I've tried deleting everything and reinstalling to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a complete answer, but this was solved by upgrading to El Capitan from Yosemite.